# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type numeric

Tags: sql-server, oracle

```
SELECT ROUND(99.12,-1);
```

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Arithmetic overflow error
>   converting expression to data type numeric.

This error will come when expression range is:

1. 95.00 to 99.99
2. 5.00 to 9.99
3. 995.00 to 999.99 and so on
   Other than that range, it works as expected.

BUT when you execute the same query in Oracle DB , it works fine and giving the expected output.

```
SELECT ROUND(99.12,-1) FROM DUAL;
ans: 100
```

so can someone explain , why it behaves like that in sqlserver2008

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute `SELECT ROUND(99.12,-1)`, the first argument is implicitly `NUMERIC(4,2)` and it will not allow for more than 2 digits before the decimal place.

The reason why 95.00 to 99.99 fails is that they are being rounded to 100 which cannot fit in a `NUMERIC(4,2)`.  Similar logic applies to your other edge cases.

Read [this MSDN article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a05bd410-ccde-44ab-af80-773ade47a30f/simple-round-call-results-in-arithmetic-overflow?forum=transactsql) for an eye-opening discussion.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(99.12 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)),-1);
```